# How to get values from the selected radio button in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have try many things but I cant get a expected output, the data coming from the api, there are 7 questions and 4 options each question, I want that If I selects the radio button I have to store the options value in another state,

```
{!data
        ? "Loading..."
        : data?.response?.data?.data?.length > 0 &&
          Object.entries(data?.response?.data?.data)?.map(
            ([key, value], index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <b>
                    <p>{value.question}</p>
                  </b>
                  <div>
                    {/* {console.log(value.options)} */}
                    {value?.options?.map((o, i) => {
                      // console.log(`key2 value`, o, i);
                      return (
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>
                          <div>
                            <FormControlLabel
                              control={<Radio />}
                              name="options"
                              value={o}
                            />
                            {/* {console.log(o)} */}
                            <input name="options" value={o} />
                            <br />
                          </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            }
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using react libraries like react-hook-forms, formik using which you can dynamically register a new fields and manage to get result using watcher in react-hook-forms and similar.

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FormControlLabel`'s `onChange` event:

```
const selectOption = (event, value) => {
   if (event.target.checked) {
      // here the radio is checked and value contains the option's value
   }
}

{!data
        ? "Loading..."
        : data?.response?.data?.data?.length > 0 &&
          Object.entries(data?.response?.data?.data)?.map(
            ([key, value], index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <b>
                    <p>{value.question}</p>
                  </b>
                  <div>
                    {/* {console.log(value.options)} */}
                    {value?.options?.map((o, i) => {
                      // console.log(`key2 value`, o, i);
                      return (
                        <React.Fragment key={i}>
                          <div>
                            <FormControlLabel
                              control={<Radio />}
                              name="options"
                              value={o}
                              onChange={(e) => selectOption(e, o)}
                            />
                            {/* {console.log(o)} */}
                            <input name="options" value={o} />
                            <br />
                          </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            }
          )}
```

Comment: its working, but If I selects multiple values of same options its also checked multiple value, I only wants a single radio checked

Comment: @ShubhamSanchela in this case you could use  `FormControlLabel`'s `checked` prop that accepts a boolean. When you select a radio, you unselect the other radio